Can a slice from the edge of a regular tetrahedron form a right triangle?
Let $PABC$ be a regular tetrahedron.  Fix a point $K$ on $PB$, and consider  $\triangle AKC$.  This triangle is isoceles (proven below).  Can it be right?
Proof that $\triangle AKC$ is isoceles: Observe that $\triangle ABK \cong \triangle CBK$ by SAS: since $PABC$ is regular, $AB \cong CB$, and $\angle ABK \cong \angle ABP \cong \angle CBP \cong \angle CPK$.  Thus, $AK \cong CK$.
If $K=B$ or $K=P$, this triangle is equilateral; otherwise, $\angle AKC > \angle KAC = \angle KCA$.  For $|CK|$ is at its minimum when it is the altitude of $\triangle PCB$, which in an isoceles triangle happens when $CK$ bisects $\angle PCB$, and a maximum when $K$ is incident with $P$ or $B$.  When $|CK|$ is at a minimum, $\angle CKA$ is at a maximum, by Euclid I.21.
My hunch is this happens when $\angle CKA$ is right, but I can't prove this.  I also can't determine the angle from $KC$ to the plane $ABC$.

$\angle AKC$ is at most the dihedral angle of the regular tetrahedron, which is $\approx 70.53^\circ$, so it can't be a right angle.

@Pranay Can you support that? It's not obvious, to me at least, why $\angle AKC$ can't be greater than the dihedral.  If $R$ is in plane 1, $T$ in plane 2, and $S$ on their common line, must $\angle RST$ be limited by the dihedral of plane 1 and 2?

As you said in your question, $\angle AKC$ is maximum when $K$ is the midpoint of $BP$. At this point, you can explicitly compute the angle to be the dihedral angle of the regular tetrahedron.

The statement in your last comment is not correct because $R$ could be $S$ and $T$ could be any line orthogonal to $S$ in plane 2. However, your problem isn't this general. Both $A$ and $C$ are fixed, and $K$ can vary only along the line $BP$, which limits what $\angle AKC$ can be.

@Pranay It certainly limits it - but you still haven't demonstrated what it limits it to.

@YvesDaoust. That’s right

Let regular tetrahedron side be $1$. $PBC$ is equilateral triangle and $CK$ length will range from altitude of equilateral triangle to side length, namely $\sqrt{3}/2$ to $1$. But for $AKC$ to be right, $CK = 1/\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}/2$, which does not fall in allowed range. Hence no right triangle is possible.

This is the best solution: direct, clear, and, once you see it, obvious.

Let me choose the coordinates of the regular tetrahedron to be
$$
P = (0,0,0),\quad A = (1,1,0),\quad B = (1,0,1), \quad C = (0,1,1).
$$
Any point $K$ on the line $BP$ is given by $(t,0,t)$ for some $0\le t\le 1$. Then,
\begin{align}
\cos \angle AKC &= \frac{|(1-t,1,-t)\cdot(-t,1,1-t)|}{\Vert(1-t,1,-t)\Vert\Vert(-t,1,1-t)\Vert}
\\
&= \frac{(1-t)^2+t^2}{(1-t)^2+1+t^2} = 1- \frac{1}{(1-t)^2 + 1 + t^2} \ge \frac13 > 0,
\end{align}
where the last inequality follows from
$$
(1-t)^2 + 1 + t^2 = 2(1-t+t^2)=2\left[\frac{3}{4}+\left(\frac12-t\right)^2\right] \ge \frac32.
$$
Therefore, $\angle AKC$ cannot be $90^\circ$.

Inscribe $PABC$ in a cube; to simplify the arithmetic, make edge length $4$: $$A = (0, 2, 0)\\ C = (2, 0, 0) \\ K_{max} = (1,1,2)$$ since $PB$ is a diagonal of the cube (on the top surface) and $K_{max}$ is its midpoint.  This gives edge lengths $\sqrt 6, \sqrt 6, \sqrt 8$, showing it is not a right triangle.
The law of cosine shows the angle is $\arccos 1/3 \approx 70.53°$, which is indeed the dihedral angle.

Within your setting, when $K=B$ or $K=P$ the angle $AKC=60°$, while when $K=(P+B)/2$ then it is known that the angle $AKC=\arccos1/3≈70.53°$. By continuity any other $K$ just provides values between those limits. Thus the answer is negative.
However, when restricting your quest just onto your headline only, i.e. neglecting the special setting of your slicing plane, then the answer could well be made positive non the less! - For that purpose let $M=(P+A)/2$, $L=(B+C)/2$, and $N=(A+C)/2$, then $MKLN$ forms a (regular) square. In fact, it just is the midsection between the edges $PC$ and $AB$. Accordingly the angle $MKL=90°$.
--- rk
